# Two column text in last paragraph latex

Tags: two-column, paragraphs, lastpage

I am looking for a way to finish my two column document in both columns. When I get the last sheet, the text is located in just one column, like this:
[image: Example]

So, I'd like that my last paragraph located in both columns. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `flushend` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{flushend}

\usepackage[numbers]{kantlipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\kant[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @RunarTrollet Thanks, I started with one and ended up with the other.

Comment: That is what I was looking for... it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

#### Twocolumn

In a `twocolumn`-paper, you can use a command to forcebreak a column, sort of like `\clearpage`, but for columns, obviously. Use `\vfill\eject` right before your last column, and it will break over.

#### Multicol

If you are using `multicol`-package, it will by default try to balance the columns, so that they will appear equally long. You can also split it manually here, using the command `\culumnbreak`

#### Comparison of output

[image]

#### twocolumn-code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\vfill\eject%
\lipsum[9]
\end{document}
```

#### Multicol-code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-6]
  %  \columnbreak
  \lipsum[7]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```